# Welche Verbform muss in einem Dass-Satz stehen?

Tags: verb, subordinate-clause, conjugation

Ist dieser Satz richtig und welche Konjugation von *mitbringen* ist korrekt?

> Ich habe vergessen, dass meine Brille **mitbringen/mitbringe/mitgebracht**

Comment: Ich habe vergessen meine Brille mitzubringen. Ich habe vergessen, dass ich meine Brille mitbringen muss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Satz ist nicht korrekt, denn der *dass*-»Satz«, den du vorschlägst, ist kein Satz. Ein Satz enthält in der Regel ein Subjekt, stets jedoch ein finites Verb. *Mitbringen* und *mitgebracht* sind infinite Formen, und *mitbringe* geht nicht, weil ein entsprechendes Subjekt fehlt.

Es gibt aber mehrere Möglichkeiten, aus dem Hauptsatz mit Nebensatzstumpf einen kompletten Satz zu machen:

- Den Nebensatz durch einen Infinitiv ersetzen. Das wäre die idiomatischste Variante.

  > Ich habe vergessen, meine Brille **mitzubringen.**

  Der Infinitiv muss mit *zu* gebildet werden, weil das Vollverb *vergessen* keines der Hilfsverben ist, die direkte Infinitive zulassen. Das *zu* wird, weil *mitbringen* trennbar ist (»Ich **bringe** meine Brille **mit**«), in das Verb eingebettet.
- Den Nebensatz ins Passiv setzen.

  > Ich habe vergessen, dass meine Brille **mitgebracht werden soll/muss.**

  Das direkte Passiv wäre zwar *mitgebracht wird*, das würde aber unterstellen, dass die Brille gebracht wird, und jetzt vorhanden ist. Du möchtest aber ausdrücken, dass die Brille eben gerade *nicht* da ist.
- Den Nebensatz mit einem Subjekt ausstatten.

  > Ich habe vergessen, dass **ich** meine Brille **mitbringen soll/muss.**

  Auch hier gilt: Ein Hilfsverb muss dazukommen. »Ich habe vergessen, dass ich meine Brille mitbringe«, unterstellt, dass du sie mitgebracht hast, aber die Tatsache vergessen hast.

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz ist falsch. Ein `dass`-Nebensatz muss immer ein Subjekt haben: "Ich habe vergessen, dass Du *(<- Subjekt)* deine Brille nicht mitgebracht hast".

Richtig wäre

> Ich habe vergessen, meine Brille mitzubringen.

Comment: Es wäre glaube ich angebracht, zu erwähnen, dass die meisten Verben beim erweiterten Infinitiv ein "zu" verlangen, und dass bei trennbaren Verben die in der Grundform zusammengeschrieben werden (*mitbringen*) das "zu" in den zusammengeschriebenen Infinitiv "eingebettet" wird (*mitzubringen*)

Comment: »Ich glaube, dass morgen gefeiert wird.« – Dieser *dass*-Satz hat kein Subjekt und ist trotzdem korrekt.